# Have a placeholder for react native picker

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to have a placeholder for the react native picker that is shown before the user clicks on it. The idea would be to have a picker that says "Nationality" and once you click and choose your country it renders the country. I want to do this without having "Nationality" as an available option in the picker.

Comment: I faced the same problem. As the solution I used a 3rdparty library [https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-dropdown](https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-dropdown). It's solid and stable enough.

Answer (score 8):

Place a first children as `<Picker.Item value='' label='Placeholder text...' />`

Comment: The problem with this approach, if I remember correctly, is that the option shows up in the list. In the end I ended up placing my placeholder in a component that renders the placeholder if there is no value selected.

Comment: That's correct @Tiagojdferreira tho it mimics the web standard implementation: http://codepen.io/sospedra/pen/ZLwrew . As you mentioned, to remove it completely render different components.

Comment: @Tiagojdferreira Could you provide the solution in a new answer and accept it? That way other people can use it as well.

Comment: @Deerloper: How can we disable the 'Select your option' using react native picker as showed in http://codepen.io/sospedra/pen/ZLwrew

Comment: @MohitPandey mmmm what do you mean with "disable"?

Comment: In the codepen, there is a first option in the list which is 'disabled'... there is no way (as far as i can see) to disable an item in the picker list.

Comment: @Tiagojdferreira could you give a bit more of an idea how your solution works ? If there is no value and you only show the placeholder, how are you able to show the picker when there is a click on it ?

Comment: @Petrov I am sorry but I did that for a company I no longer work for, so I do not have access to the code. If I remember correctly we had a Label component that was responsible for rendering the result, and a picker inside it.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not clear this is the right way.

```
<Picker selectedValue={locals.value}
onValueChange={value => {
    if (value != "0")
        this.pickerValueChange(value)

    // so it won't care if header is selected...
}}>
    <Picker.Item label="Select Type" value="0" />
    <Picker.Item label="Diesel" value="Diesel" />
    <Picker.Item label="Gas" value="Gas" />
    <Picker.Item label="Electricity" value="Electricity" /> 
</Picker>
```

**pickerValueChange** function:

```
pickerValueChange = val => {
    // state change or whatever you want to perform on picker update
}
```

Comment: its a good one but you can rather use easier values to compare for header item. I'm editing you answer for that!

Answer (score 4):

You may use native-base's picker instead.

**1. Run:**

```
npm i native-base --save
```

**2. Import it as:**

```
import {Picker} from 'native-base';
```

**3. Use it as:**

```
<Picker
placeholder="Start Year" // yipeee, placeholder
iosIcon={<Ionicons name="ios-arrow-down" />} // right icon
selectedValue={this.state.selected_id} // your selected item value
style={{
    // your styles
}}
// onValueChange={this.onValueChange.bind(this)} // use it the way it suites you
onValueChange={(v)=>this.setState({selected_id:v})} // use it the way it suites you
>


 <Picker.Item label="Val 1" value="1" />
   <Picker.Item label="Val 2" value="2" />
   <Picker.Item label="Val 3" value="3" />

</Picker>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a state in the same component you can filter the elements once the user have been chosen an element.

For example:

```
...
const [selectedValue, setValue] = useState(0)
const values = ['Your placeholder', 'Option A', 'Option B', 'Option C']
....
        <Picker
          mode="dropdown"
          selectedValue={selectedValue}
          onValueChange={(itemValue) => setValue(itemValue)}
        >
          {values
            .filter((value, index) => selectedValue === 0 ? value : index === 0 ? false : value)
            .map((value, index) => (
              <Picker.Item label={value} value={value} key={index} />
            ))}
        </Picker>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for this as well and solved it on my own as below. Hope this helps other people as well.

1. make a function that checks for an empty value.

```
  const isPlaceholder = (value) => {
    return value == "";
  }
```

2. We are setting the first option as the placeholder, but changing the style to make it look like the placeholder if the value is empty (which we set the placeholder value as "").

If the option selected has value as empty, then we use styles.placeholder. Else, we just use normal style (styles.picker).

```
            <Picker
              selectedValue={gender}
              style={
                isPlaceholder(gender) ? (styles.placeholder) : (
                  styles.picker
                )}

              onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setGender(itemValue)}
              <Picker.Item color="grey" label="Choose Gender..." value="" /> 

// the first option is grey in the 
// picker to make it more like a title 

              <Picker.Item label="Male" value="male" />
              <Picker.Item label="Female" value="female" />
            </Picker>
```

Styling for placeholder and values

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  placeholder: {
    height: 50, width: '100%',
    color: "grey",  // PLACE HOLDER COLOR
  },
 picker: {
    height: 50, width: '100%',
    color: "blue",  // VALUE COLOR
  },
)}
```